# Поиск элемента Selenium Python

Tags: html, python, selenium

В HTML есть несколько элементом с одним "class". Можно ли через find_elements_by_class_name обратиться ко второму элементу в html с этим классом.
Для аналогии в JS это выглядит так: document.getElementsByClass('class')[1]

Вот страница: https://gs.nike.com/?checkoutId=272db2ea-23f7-4feb-8399-b2536f70cc91&launchId=5c922ed1-1cc7-4a5c-8811-6ec777836b6d&skuId=17eef24d-57f2-5c93-8452-d02283fa2ef0&country=RU&locale=ru&appId=com.nike.commerce.snkrs.web&returnUrl=https:%2F%2Fwww.nike.com%2Fru%2Flaunch%2Ft%2Fair-max-90-undefeated-black1%2F
Искомый объект - первая кнопка "Сохранить и продолжить"

Comment: Угу, попробуйте: `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('class')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых - надо было указать сайт, чтобы можно было найти альтернативу. Во-вторых - можно использовать find_element_by_id или find_element_by_xpath

Answer (score 0):

По документации метод [find_elements_by_class_name](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name) как раз и возвращает список элементов с указанным `class`, поэтому код будет похожим на аналог в js:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('class')[1]
```

Но я советую проверять размер списка элементов, чтобы не было исключения о выходе за пределы списка, пример:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('class')
if len(elements) > 1:
    print(elements[1])
```